# Why does the presence of `n` in the input sentence before `\n` give wrong output?

Tags: c, input, output, user-input

I want to input a sentence (containing any possible characters) and print it. But there is a catch. If there is a `\n` in the sentence then only the part of the sentence before `\n` should be printed out (i.e. `\n` should signify the end of the inputted sentence). I wrote a code for this situation :

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    char ch[100];
    printf("Enter a sentence");
    scanf("%99[^\\n]",&ch);
    printf("%s",ch);
}
```

This code seems to work fine but it fails in a certain situation. 
If there is the character `n` anywhere in the sentence before `\n` then it prints only the first word of the sentence! Why does this happen? How can I fix this bug?

This case works fine:
[image]

But in this case it fails:

[image]

---

Detail from comments:

[Q:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760114/why-does-the-presence-of-n-in-the-input-sentence-before-n-give-wrong-output/45760599#comment78478225_45760114) Do you want to to stop at a newline, or at a backslash followed by n?
[A:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760114/why-does-the-presence-of-n-in-the-input-sentence-before-n-give-wrong-output/45760599#comment78478241_45760114) slash followed by n

Comment: The scanset only considers individual characters. It does not consider character pairs. You'll find it also stopping at "\" alone.

Comment: @EOF Then how can I make it stop at occurence of \ immediately followed by `n`. Is there any way to make this happen with `scanf` ?

Comment: Do you want to to stop at a newline, or at a backslash followed by `n`?

Comment: @interjay slash followed by `n`

Comment: @Blue you cannot match 2 characters in succession with `scanf`. Or you can, but you cannot continue after a match failure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[]` conversion specifier of `scanf()` works by defining an accepted (or, with `^`, rejected) **set** of characters. So `%[^\\n]` will stop scanning at the first `\` **or** the first `n` -> You can't solve your problem with `scanf()`.

You should just read a line of input with `fgets()` and search for an occurence of `"\\n"` with `strstr()`.

---

Side note: there's an error in your program:

```
char ch[100];
scanf("%99[^\\n]",&ch);
```

`ch` evaluates as a pointer to the first element of the array (so, would be fine as parameter for `scanf()`), while `&ch` evaluates to a *pointer to the array*, which is not what `scanf()` expects.

<sup>(the difference is in the type, the address will be the same)</sup>

Comment: Probably helpful (while a little cynical) additional material: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html which follows this answers general idea.

Comment: Is it impossible to make this happen with `scanf()` ? I know it can be done with other functions like the one you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the error (in your side note). Do you know any fix for it?

Comment: @Blue yes, impossible. `scanf()` just doesn't have a conversion specifier that compares *sequences* of characters. While it **can** match *literal* strings, anything you would put before that would *greedily* match and you'd never reach your *literal* part.

Comment: @Blue the fix is there, when using `scanf()` with a string conversion on a `char` array, just don't use `&`.

Comment: Thanks! Nice answer :)

Comment: @Yunnosch haha, thanks for suggesting my document ;)

Comment: I did not really notice it is actually yours, this puts my describing it as "cynical" (right in your face) in an interesting light. Thanks for taking it kindly. You/it deserves every credit.

Comment: @Yunnosch and a bit to [one contributor so far](https://github.com/Zirias/webdocs/commits/master). I see what  you mean, I just thought it's more interesting to read, following a possible road along all the *classic* pitfalls ;)

Answer (score 1):

OP's [calcification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760114/why-does-the-presence-of-n-in-the-input-sentence-before-n-give-wrong-output/45760599#comment78478241_45760114) negated the first part of this answer.

---

OP has not formed the desired *scan set* for the `"%[...]"` specifier.

`"%99[^\\n]"` accepts any character except `'\\'` and `'n'`.

Certainly OP wants `"%99[^\n]"`.  `\\` changed to `\` to accept any character except `'\n'`.

---

Yet I would like to take the goal up a bit.  This part is only for pedantic code.

> input a sentence (containing any possible characters)

How would code handle this if the *null character* `'\0'` was included in that "any possible character"?

Note that inputting a *null character* is not often easy from a keyboard.

Interestingly `"%99[^\n]"` will scan up to 99 characters (except a `'\n'`) **including** the *null character*.  Yet the below code prints `ch` as it it were a *string* and not a general array of characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char ch[100];
    printf("Enter a sentence\n");
    if (scanf("%99[^\n]", ch) != 1) {
      ch[0] = '\0';  // Handle a line of only `'\n``, EOF, or error
    }
    printf("%s",ch);
}
```

To accomplish this esoteric goal with `scanf()` (not the best tool in the shed), record the length of the scan and then print the array.

```
int main(void) {
    char ch[100];
    int n;
    printf("Enter a sentence\n");

    if (scanf("%99[^\n]%n", ch, &n) != 1) {
      n = 0; // If scanning stopped right away, set length `n` to 0
    }
    // Write as an array
    fwrite(ch, sizeof ch[0], n, stdout);
}
```

Comment: "*Certainly OP wants `"%99[^\n]"`*" <- no ;) -- but interesting stuff about `NUL` :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Perhsp.  Title is < ... input sentence before `\n` give wrong output?> Had OP titled it < input sentence before `"\n"` give wrong output?> I would readily agree.  Yet as usual, the details of a post can conflict and may only approximate OP's true intent.

Comment: I think the question is clear enough, but if you have doubts, [see this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760114/why-does-the-presence-of-n-in-the-input-sentence-before-n-give-wrong-output/45760599#comment78478241_45760114).

Comment: @FelixPalmen The clarifying comment arrived after my answer's work was begun -  Posted edited to include that information.  [Related issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298108/2410359)

Comment: Good edit! Although I think it was possible to deduce he really meant a *literal* `\n`, this is so uncommon that it should be explicitly mentioned.